# All margins are equal, but some margins are more equal than others

Tags: css, margin, center, centering

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This CSS horizontally centers a block element.

Is it possible to offset `auto` margins' proportions? For instance, make the left margin twice as big as the right margin?

Comment: what if we make use of percentages like margin:0 50% 0 25%; like so ?

Comment: PLUS 1 (since `+1` isn't allowed >:( )  just for the Animal Farm reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some empty divs and "flex" the left side at twice the rate:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  flex: 2
}

#content {
  width:100px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#right {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="content">content</div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of empty divs you could use `::before` and `::after`.